# Same headerBackImageSource for Android and for iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

[image]
How can I use chevron both for Android and iOS devices? What would be a proper way of using one default icon cross-platformingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to get your own image or svg of a chevron and put it in as the headerBackImageSource. Or you could build a custom header under the option of headerLeft like so:

```
        import chevron from './assets/chevron.png'

        <App.Screen
          options={() => ({
            title: Enrollment,
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            headerStyle: // styles,
            headerLeft: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.goBack}>
                <Image
                  source={chevron}
                  style={{ height: 16, width: 16 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
        })}
          name="Enrollment Screen"
          component={EnrollmentScreen}
        />
      </App.Navigator>
```

or you could use the headerBackImage option

```
headerBackImage: () => <Chevron style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
```